# How OSB proxy server can read new emails on mail server through a webservice?

Tags: web-services, email, osb, oracle-service-bus

I have to read new emails that arrive into a mail server(Pop3/Imap). The emails must be transformed from text format into soap message and then routed to another OSB Proxy Service.
Can I use a web service for the transformation? When and how calling it?

Any suggestions will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Fairlie

Comment: Web Service doesn't do transformation. You have to use xquery to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is surely possible.

1. Create a service account. Use the username and password for the mail account and select type as Static.
2. Create an OSB Proxy service of Messaging Service Type. On Protocol configuration page, select email as the protocol and provide the details.
3. In the Message flow you can make the necessary transformations using Xquery
4. Call any service that you wish to call using either Routing, Service Callout or Publish.

Comment: Hi Palakmathur, thanks for your suggestions. I did not think about using Xquery before. So, after transforming my email text into Soap(using XQuery) message I have only to call the other webservice and route my message to it. Perfect. Thanks again.